# Count by value in mysql with joins

Tags: mysql, join

I've got three tables: users, topics, and posts which are structured like this:

```
--users
----id
----name
----email
----password
----profile_pic

--topics
----id
----topic_title
----topic_category
----topic_content
----author_id

--comments
----id
----topic_id
----author_id
----comment
----mood
```

A sql fiddle of this is at: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/8e5241

Now what I need to do is to query all topics and get the author information of each plus the comment count on each topic. This was easy enough to do with this query:

```
SELECT 
  topics.id, 
  topics.topic_title, 
  topics.topic_category, 
  topics.topic_content, 
  topics.author_id, 
  users.name, 
  users.profile_pic, 
  topics.created_at, 
  count(comments.id) AS comments 
FROM 
  topics 
JOIN 
  users 
ON 
  users.id = topics.author_id 
LEFT JOIN 
  comments 
ON 
  topics.id = comments.topic_id 
GROUP BY 
  topics.id 
ORDER BY 
  topics.created_at 
DESC
```

Which returns an sql result of:

```
topic_title | created_at | id | topic_category | author_id | topic_content | name | profile_pic | comments
```

This works fine, the problem is I don't just need an overall comment count. The mood field in the comments table can have 3 possible values (0, 1, 2) and I need to count the amount of comments with each value.

I tried changing

```
count(comments.id)
```

in the above query to

```
count(comments.mood=0) AS happy, count(comments.mood=1) AS sad, count(comments.mood=2) AS angry
```

but that returns the same value for each of the result fields. Is there any way to do this in a single mySQL query?

Comment: you can try sum(comments.mood=0) as happy and so on..

Comment: LEt me add that as an aswer !

Comment: @Pavel Thanks for providing the SQL fiddle, my answer is of course completely wrong. Sorry for that, I've deleted it.

Comment: @Tomalak thanks for your time. The answer I have now is still not ideal (due to the NULL values), but it'll have to work until I find a better solution.

Comment: @PavelRogala `SUM(CASE WHEN comments.mood = 0 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS comments_happy` (etc) won't produce NULL values. Or you wrap `SUM(comments.mood = 0)` in `IFNULL()`. Using `COUNT(CASE comments.mood WHEN 0 THEN 1 END) AS comments_happy` would work as well.

Comment: Ah, perfect. The IFNULL() solved it. I hadn't thought of that. Thanks again for your help. :)

Comment: You can edit the accepted answer to include that detail. Making it possible to edit any post is one of the nicer features of the site.

Comment: Yeah, that would be better then just adding my own answer with the query ... :) Sorry.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to use sum() to do such operation as

```
sum(comments.mood=0) as happy,
sum(comments.mood=1) as sad,
sum(comments.mood=2) as angry,
```

Edit by @Pavel: I'll just share the final query that I used to get the correct results which I based on answers given by @Abhik Chakraborty and @Tomalak.

```
SELECT 
    topics.id, 
    topics.topic_title, 
    topics.topic_category, 
    topics.topic_content, 
    topics.author_id, 
    users.name AS author_name, 
    users.profile_pic, 
    topics.created_at, 
    IFNULL(SUM(comments.mood=0),0) AS comments_happy, 
    IFNULL(SUM(comments.mood=1),0) AS comments_sad, 
    IFNULL(SUM(comments.mood=2),0) AS comments_angry 
  FROM 
    topics 
  JOIN 
    users 
  ON 
    users.id = topics.author_id 
  LEFT JOIN 
    comments 
  ON topics.id = comments.topic_id 
  GROUP BY 
    topics.id 
  ORDER BY 
    topics.created_at 
  DESC
```